# Redis usecase for notification system

Tags: notifications, nosql, redis

Does anyone know the usecases for notification system (redis).

I tried many patterns, but not satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

I would think using a [List](http://redis.io/commands#list) to create a queue would be the best approach. You can push a JSON document or some other serialized data representing the notice onto the list then pop them off as they are delivered (or keep them in the list depending upon your need). Using things like [LRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) you can easily paginate to handle any number of notices.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Staircar: Redis-powered notifications](http://engineering.tumblr.com/post/7819252942/staircar-redis-powered-notifications). Tumblr team actually uses Redis SortedSet for notifications:

*Redis Sorted Sets fit the characteristics of notifications perfectly, without the I/O and concurrency pitfalls of implementing a similar structure in MySQL. Sorted sets in Redis are ordered by a score (unix timestamp in our case), contain unique elements (non-repeating collections of strings in redis speak), can be trimmed or appended to cheaply, and are keyed off, well, a key (user in our case)*

Comment: I already seen Tumblr link, but not helpful.  can u provide me source code link

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Thoonk. It produces like pub/sub events that correspond to publish/edit/retract/resorts on higher level objects called feeds. It works well for notification inboxes and application state changes.

The contract/schema https://github.com/andyet/thoonk.js/blob/master/contract.txt provides a lot of recipes that you may be interested in.

Comment: Your link is broken (404).